# Ui router resolve variable remain undefined in component constructor

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have this UI router state with a component attached to it:

```
export const exchangeState = {
    name: 'exchange',
    url: '/exchange',
    component: ExchangeMainComponent,
    resolve: [
        {
            token: 'fromResolve',
            resolveFn: () => {
                return 'string from resolve';
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

In component's constructor I trying to access `fromResolve` but it returns undefined. This is the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-exchange-main',
  templateUrl: './exchange-main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./exchange-main.component.css']
})
export class ExchangeMainComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input('fromResolve') fromResolve: string;
    constructor() {
        console.log(this.fromResolve); // <- undefined
    }
    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

`fromResolve` showing up correctly in the view.

How can I have it's value in the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Input` values are first available in `OnChanges` life cycle hook. The order of execution is...

```
constructor -> OnChanges -> OnInit ....
```

So you can either access it in `OnChanges` or `OnInit`, but not in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular RouterModule you should do something like this

```
fromResolve: string;
constructor(private router: ActivatedRouter) {
 this.route.data
  .subscribe((data: { fromResolve: string}) => {
    this.fromResolve= data.fromResolve;
  });
}
```

You should modify you router in a way which is described here:

[Fetch data before navigating](https://angular.io/guide/router#fetch-data-before-navigating)

Comment: this seems to be working only for RouterModule but not for UIRouterModule

Comment: Yes you have right, but why you don't using Angular RouterModule ?

Comment: right now I'm just checking out how UIrouter is working

Comment: Ok, i understand. What I wrote is for Angular RouterModule